# Eclipse Indigo 64-bit severe memory leaks

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks

I'm working with Eclipse Indigo, 64-bit version in 64-bit Windows 7 and the most recent version of 64-bit Java SDK.  Using standard Java and XML as well as Pydev plugins. My machine has 4 GB of RAM.

When I try to open, edit, and search large XML files (42,000 lines or so) in either the XML perspective or the plaintext editor of Eclipse, the program locks up.  The heap monitor in Eclipse becomes fully consumed.  Waiting to see if the deadlock will halt doesn't help, and I have to restart Eclipse to get it functional again.

Any ideas what the problem is here?  Bad version of Java? Eclipse Indigo or 64-bit  version not road-ready to go yet?

Comment: should not it be asked on the eclipse forum instead?

Comment: sorry, new member. Is it possible to move the question now?

Comment: Well, I meant you to ask here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/ Maybe people can answer you here, i'm not telling you that you should not ask here, but saying that people there knows a lot about eclipse's development.

Comment: Oh I see!  I might give cross-posting a try as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

42K is a really big file for the poor XML editor. It's likely that it's just taking a really long time to deal with this. I would file a bug against the webtools project in Eclipse and attach your file (if you don't mind sharing).

I would capture the thread dump (google "java thread dump" if you don't know how to do this) a few times while it's working so that you can get a stack trace of what's happening which might be useful to the Eclipse folks.

There is nothing wrong with Eclipse Indigo or 64 bit Eclipse (I and many others use those just fine for normal work).